# How to convert all the blank values of a JSON object to hyphens?

Tags: javascript

Here is my sample response:

```
var jsonData1 = [{
  firstName: "Sam",
  age: "10"
}, {
  firstName: "John",
  age: "11"
}, {
  firstName: "Jack",
  age: "12"
}, {
  firstName: "Pam",
  age: "13"
}, {
  firstName: "",
  age: "14"
}, {
  firstName: "Mitch",
  age: ""
}];
```

All I want is, wherever I have a blank string in any field, to show it as zero. I want to do it using plain JS, no lodash, no jQuery.

Comment: Please learn [the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

Comment: Please reconcile your title with the description.

Comment: You would want to use `jsonData1.map((x)=>{});`

Answer (score 1):

You can write this in one line of code:

```
jsonData1.forEach(o => Object.keys(o).forEach(key => o[key] === '' && (o[key] = '-')))
```

Comment: This won't work - `Object.keys()` takes an object, not a function.

Comment: I want old es5 syntax, using plain for loops

Comment: Looks better! I would recommend using triple equals comparison instead of double equals to avoid accidental type coercion though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the given data structure, I'd approach it like this:

- loop through the elements in the array with `Array.forEach()`
- loop through the properties in the element with `Object.keys(person).forEach()`
- check for emptystring and replace

Like this:

```
jsonData1.forEach(person => {
     Object.keys(person).forEach(key => {
         if (person[key] === "") person[key] = "-";
     });
});
```

Comment: I want to write in old JS style with just for loops

Comment: Are you sure? I never use `for` anymore - it's too fiddly. But if you want!

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonData1 = jsonData1.map(item=>{
    for(let key in item){
        if(item[key].length === 0) item[key] = 0;
    }
    return item;
})
```

**With Simple Loop**

```
for(let i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    let keys = Object.keys(data[i]); //returns an array of keys of object
    for(let key = 0;key<keys.length;key++){ 
        let keyName = keys[key];
        if(data[i][keyName].length === 0) data[i][keyName] = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit too eager - you'll also replace empty arrays, which isn't what the questioner wanted.

Comment: I want to write in old syntax using plain for loop

Answer (score 0):

As you do have an array, you can simply iterate over it:

```
for (var i=0;i<jsonData1.length;i++) {
    if (jsonData1[i].age==="")
        jsonData1[i].age = 0;
    if (jsonData1[i].firstName==="")
        jsonData1[i].firstName = "Unknown";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't cover the case for firstName

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work - jsonData[i].age.length is a number, so will never be equal to "".

Comment: Looks better, although the `Unknown` seems to come out of nowhere!

Comment: Of course you both are right, fixed, thanks! I got mixed uo when going from the ' .length===0 ' to the ' =="" ' approach. The firstName thing i missed because setting a name to zero didn't fit my mind ;-)   -  for the general approach, please refer to the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

> The `for...of` statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, Array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables.

```js
var jsonData1 = [{
  firstName: "Sam",
  age: "10"}, {
  firstName: "John",
  age: "11"},{
  firstName: "Jack",
  age: "12"},{
  firstName: "Pam",
  age: "13"},{
  firstName: "",
  age: "14"},{
  firstName: "Mitch",
  age: ""
}];

for(var p of jsonData1){
  if(p.firstName.trim()=="") p.firstName="0";
  if(p.age.trim()=="") p.age="0"
}

console.log(jsonData1);
```

Comment: I want to write in old syntax, plain for loops

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 let newData = jsonData1.forEach(function(data) {
     for(ans in data) {
        If(data[ans] === "") data[ans] = 0;
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `forEach` loop

```js
var jsonData1 = [
 {
firstName: "Sam",
age: "10"
  },
 {
firstName: "John",
age: "11"
  },
 {
firstName: "Jack",
age: "12"
  },
  {
firstName: "Pam",
age: "13"
  },
  {
firstName: "",
age: "14"
 },
 {
firstName: "Mitch",
age: ""
}
 ];
 jsonData1.forEach((e)=>{Object.keys(e).forEach((x)=>e[x]==""?e[x]=0:false)})
 console.log(jsonData1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick for nested objects:

```
const convertObj = obj => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (obj[key] === '') {
            obj[key] = 0
        } else if (obj[key] instanceof Object) {
            convertObj(obj[key])
        }
    })

    return obj
}
```

Sample test:

```
const jsonData1 = [
   {
        firstName: "Mitch",
        age: "",
        nested_test: [
            {
                foo: 'bar',
                age: ''
            }
        ],
        nested_object: {
            foo: 'bar',
            age: ''
        }
    }
]
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Mitch",
    "age": 0,
    "nested_array": [
      {
        "foo": "bar",
        "age": 0
      }
    ],
    "nested_object": {
      "foo": "bar",
      "age": 0
    }
  }
]
```